# Excel Table Slicer - Distinct count of rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to slice and dice my data set and I got one strange "issue", I actually cant do distinct count which is gonna change values when I choose something on slicer. if I select year 2020 or 2019 it is giving always the total numbers of values and specific values for certain year. I know I can do it in Pivot tables but for now I am just in normal excel table format. Is there a way to workaround to make it more dynamic?

I am using this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(Ism_V[Charge (CS)];Ism_V[Charge (CS)]))
```

[image: Excerpt of data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this to work. Make this an array formula (SHFT-CTRL-ENTER) after entering it. Returned counts are distinct values.

```
    =SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,  OFFSET(Table1[Another],  MATCH(ROW(Table1[Another]),  ROW(Table1[Another]))-1,  0,  1)), COUNTIF(Table1[Another], "<"&Table1[Another]), ""), COUNTIF(Table1[Another], "<"&Table1[Another]))>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow...thanks man. This works as it should be - but it is a huge monster so far :D